# Use html-webpack-plugin with string-replace-loader in webpack

Tags: javascript, html, build, webpack, webpack-html-loader

I'm trying to replace a variable in index.html that looks like this:

`<meta name='author' content=$variable>`

In the config file I use:

```
  {
    test: /index\.html$/,
    loader: 'string-replace',
    query: {
      search: '$variable',
      replace: 'stuff to inject',
    },
  }
```

In the `loaders` array, and then in `plugins`:

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  template: conf.path.src('src/index.html'),
  inject: true,
})
```

But this setting results in:

`ERROR in ./~/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./src/index.html
    Module parse failed (...)  Unexpected token (1:0)
    You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.`

Do you have any ideas what this can be caused by or how can I debug this?

Comment: For debugging I am using [iron-node](https://github.com/s-a/iron-node) which allows to add debugger statements to node modules

Answer (score 6):

It's caused because of `string-replace-plugin` expects a module that exporting a string. You should convert HTML file to CommonJS module.

For example, this is the way by using [`raw-loader`](https://github.com/webpack/raw-loader/blob/master/index.js):

first, add quotes to content attribute in html

```
<meta name='author' content='$variable'>`
```

and

```
{
    test: /index\.html$/,
    loader: 'string-replace?search=$variable&replace=stuff to inject!raw'
  }
```

Comment: Nice one - do you think we could improve the html-webpack-plugin somehow to improve the error message?

Answer (score 3):

Konstantin's answer works fine and is good if you want to replace one value. I wanted to replace multiple values so added the following to my `loaders` array

```
  {
    test: /\.html$/,
    loader: 'raw'
  },
  {
    test: /\.html$/,
    loader: 'string-replace',
    query: {
      multiple: [
        {search: '$variable1', replace: 'replacement 1'},
        {search: '$variable2', replace: 'replacement 2'}
      ]
    }
  }
```

The key change is to first run your html file through the `raw` loader, and then you can use all the normal config for the `string-replace-loader`.

Comment: This worked in webpack 1.X but i think it is not working with webpack 2 & 3.

Answer (score 3):

An update to [@Jonathon Blok](https://stackoverflow.com/users/785048/jonathon-blok)'s answer, but for Webpack 4, with some slight modifications:

- had to `npm install --save-dev string-replace-loader@2`.
- had to use `'raw-loader'` and `'string-replace-loader'` identifiers because webpack@4 insisted.
- used `options:` instead of `query:` as per the `string-replace-loader` docs.

#### For Webpack 4

```
{
  test: /.*\.html$/,
  loader: 'raw-loader',
},
{
  test: /.*\.html$/,
  loader: 'string-replace-loader',
  options: {
    multiple: [
      {search: '$variable1', replace: 'replacement 1'},
      {search: '$variable2', replace: 'replacement 2'}            ]
  }
}
```

As before,

> The key change is to first run your html file through the raw loader, and then you can use all the normal config for the string-replace-loader.

#### For Webpack 5

Same as above should work for Webpack 5, though I haven't tested it, by omitting the `@2` and installing string-loader with `npm install --save-dev string-replace-loader`.  This is because v3 of the string-replace-loader is expected to work with Webpack 5+, as per the [string-replace-loader docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/string-replace-loader).